# Can multiple revisions of a node (entity) have different languages?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, workflows

For example, we have a published English node, and a user creates a new draft and set the language (from the node form) to German and creates a new revision. This way the latest revision of the node is in a different language. This result is couple of issue that I am trying to understand:

1. Is this allowed?
2. Can users create multiple drafts in different languages?

When I tried to do that on vanilla drupal 8 I found a few bugs. One issue that it would just throw fatal error when trying it with Article content type because it has synchronized fields that triggers some validations which throw the error. [This has been reported.](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2995655)
But if you try this with basic page type, a draft in a different language is created. If you delete the draft the entire node is deleted. I would love to know how the language selector on node forms is supposed to work with revisions?

Comment: Have you simply tried it yourself already? Is it working? Can you switch back and forth?

Comment: Yes, and I found bugs. One issue that it would just throw fatal error. Another was with content moderation I reported that. But if you circumvent the conditions that cause fatal error  a draft in a different language is created.if you delete the draft the entire node is deleted. I'm simply trying to understand how content language is supposed to work with revisions

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is key info. You should add that to your question.